# How to debug Istio Authorization Policy?

Tags: istio

It is not very straightforward to test AuthorizationPolicy CRD as per https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#AuthorizationPolicy-Action. I want to make sure that the AuthorizationPolicy I wrote can ALLOW the requests I want to allow, and DENY those I don't. But there are multiple hops of workloads in my cluster, so when the request failed, I have no idea where to look at for debugging the authorization rules.

**Previous Research**

I found this [Debugging Authorization](https://istio.io/v1.0/help/ops/security/debugging-authorization/) article but it was for IstioIdle 1.0. But I am using Istio 1.9, there are some differences in terms of istio architecture.

#### Edit

I have a Kubeflow app [deployment guide](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/) which has old authorization policy (see ClusterRbacConfig in [this](https://istio.io/v1.4/blog/2019/v1beta1-authorization-policy/)). I want to preserve the original role-based access control policy, but use the new `AuthorizatonPolicy` CRD to achieve it.

Comment: Can you provide more information about environment and config yaml files ?

Comment: Thank you @Malgorzata, I added more information. But my question is more about tooling on latest version of Istio, because the issue itself is too convoluted to describe. But having a debugging tool can help a lot.